# Are all the terms in the Inclusion Exclusion Principle Independent of One Another?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The terms in the inclusion exclusion principle are simply the (sizes of) the sets themselves and all the possible combinations of $i$ intersections.

And since the intersections of $k$ sets  themselves can be expressed as intersections with itself and the  all the possible combinations of $i$ ($i>k$)  intersections:
e.g 
\begin{multline}X_1∩X_2∩X_3 = (X_1∩X_2∩X_3)' + (X_1∩X_2∩X_3)∩X_4 + \cdots\\ - (X_1∩X_2∩X_3)∩X_4∩X_5 +\cdots \end{multline}
(where $X'$ refers to elements exclusive to $X$)

and $(X_1∩X_2∩X_3)'$ term is exclusive only to $X_1∩X_2∩X_3,$

Then can I say that all the terms in the formula are  independent of each other (i.e can be any whole number), provided that the size of any of the intersections of set $X$  is less than or equal to the size of set $X$?

i.e $|X ∩ S| \leq |X|$,
where $X$ and $S$ can be any set or intersection of sets

Comment: The notation $X'$ is one of the ways people write "the complement of $X$", which informally means "set of elements **not in** $X$", which is apparently not what you mean. When you write $(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)'$, do you actually mean $(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)\setminus(X_4\cup X_5\cup\cdots)$, that is, $(X_1\cap X_2\cap X_3)$ "minus" all the elements of the union of all the other sets?

Comment: Did you mean to take the sizes of all the set intersections in the long formula? Otherwise I am not sure how to interpret it when you write $\cdots - (X_1∩X_2∩X_3)∩X_4∩X_5$.

Comment: Does this question have some relationship to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390569/is-it-always-possible-to-distribute-n-elements-into-k-sets-with-each-set-having/3438490#3438490?

Comment: Hello David, yes it does. My group is writing a  combinatorics paper which applies set theory.   I am  searching for a general rule(s) to tell which set constructions are possible and which are impossible; i.e given some cardinalities of some sets and the cardinalities of their intersections, is the construction possible? I have a hunch the answer lies in the inclusion exclusion principle. You seen quite an expert on this topic. If you are willing to collaborate with us, please indicate. We'll make you a co author.

Answer (score 3):

Let $I$ be some finite set. For each subset $J\subseteq I$, let $n_J$ be some non-negative integer. Under what conditions can we find a family of sets $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ such that

$$\left|\bigcap_{i\in J} A_i\right|=n_J$$

for all $J$?

The answer is definitely not that it's possible for any family of integers $(n_J)$. First of all, we of course need $n_J\leq n_K$ for $K\subseteq J$, because a family of sets must always be smaller than the intersection of a subfamily of those sets. But that still isn't enough. For example, suppose that for a family of three sets $A, B, C$ we wanted

$$\begin{align}
|A\cap B\cap C|&=1\\
|A\cap B|&=3\\
|A\cap C|&=3\\
|A|&=4
\end{align}$$

The problem is that this implies that $|A\cap B\cap\overline C|$ and $|A\cap C\cap\overline B|$ each contain two elements, which along with the one element $|A\cap B\cap C|$ means $A$ already has $5$ elements. You can try picturing this logic with a [Venn diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Inclusion-exclusion.svg/1280px-Inclusion-exclusion.svg.png).

In fact the values $n_J$ are bound together by a matrix of linear inequations such as

$$|A\cap B|+|A\cap B|-|A\cap B\cap C|\leq |A|$$

One way of teasing out these inequalities is to express everthing in terms of the variables $|\bigcap_i A_i^{x_i}|$, where each $x_i$ is either the set complement operator (relative to $\bigcup_i A_i$) or nothing. These sets are simply the "minimal regions" of a Venn diagram, the parts that you could imagine filling in a single click with the paint bucket tool in a drawing program. These cardinalities are indeed all independent of one another, and the terms of the Inclusion-Exclusion equation can be expressed as linear combinations of them. Inverting that matrix should give you a set of equations with linear combinations of the I-E terms on the right, and the sizes of the minimal regions on the left. A necessary and sufficient condition for a candidate set of a I-E terms to be feasible is then that the values on the left hand side of that system all be non-negative.